# Reset Embedded H2 database periodically

Tags: reset, h2

I'm setting up a new version of my application in a demo server and would love to find a way of resetting the database daily. I guess I can always have a cron job executing drop and create queries but I'm looking for a cleaner approach. I tried using a special persistence unit with drop-create approach but it doesn't work as the system connects and disconnects from the server frequently (on demand).

Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

H2 supports a special SQL statement to [drop all objects](http://h2database.com/html/commands.html#drop_all_objects):

```
DROP ALL OBJECTS [DELETE FILES]
```

If you don't want to drop all tables, you might want to use [truncate table](http://h2database.com/html/commands.html#truncate_table):

```
TRUNCATE TABLE
```

Comment: TRUNCATE TABLE doesn't reset AUTO_INCREMENT counters to zero:(

Comment: @Nazar, yes, this is the same behavior as other databases, for example PostgreSQL (using `serial`). I think it's the correct behavior, as the values might be used in other tables.

Comment: @ThomasMueller - `JdbcDataSource ds = new JdbcDataSource(); ds.setURL("jdbc:h2:~/mydb"); ds.setUser("sa"); ds.setPassword("pass");...etc`
I use this to create an embedded db in my eclipse java project. How do I drop the db - mydb ? Thanks.

Comment: @ThomasMueller - Also, can you please tell me the location of the embedded db in the harddrive ? I asked it as a question at - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25587693/how-do-i-create-a-h2-database-inside-a-java-project-in-eclipse. Thank you.

Answer (score 24):

As this response is the first Google result for "reset H2 database", I post my solution below :

*After each JUnit @tests* :

- Disable integrity constraint
- List all tables in the (default) PUBLIC schema
- Truncate all tables
- List all sequences in the (default) PUBLIC schema
- Reset all sequences
- Reenable the constraints.

  ```
  @After
  public void tearDown() {
      try {
          clearDatabase();
      } catch (Exception e) {
          Fail.fail(e.getMessage());
      }
  }

  public void clearDatabase() throws SQLException {
      Connection c = datasource.getConnection();
      Statement s = c.createStatement();

      // Disable FK
      s.execute("SET REFERENTIAL_INTEGRITY FALSE");

      // Find all tables and truncate them
      Set<String> tables = new HashSet<String>();
      ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES  where TABLE_SCHEMA='PUBLIC'");
      while (rs.next()) {
          tables.add(rs.getString(1));
      }
      rs.close();
      for (String table : tables) {
          s.executeUpdate("TRUNCATE TABLE " + table);
      }

      // Idem for sequences
      Set<String> sequences = new HashSet<String>();
      rs = s.executeQuery("SELECT SEQUENCE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SEQUENCES WHERE SEQUENCE_SCHEMA='PUBLIC'");
      while (rs.next()) {
          sequences.add(rs.getString(1));
      }
      rs.close();
      for (String seq : sequences) {
          s.executeUpdate("ALTER SEQUENCE " + seq + " RESTART WITH 1");
      }

      // Enable FK
      s.execute("SET REFERENTIAL_INTEGRITY TRUE");
      s.close();
      c.close();
  }
  ```

The other solution would be to recreatethe database at the begining of each tests. But that might be too long in case of big DB.

Comment: I am using this in a `org.junit.rules.TestRule` - it resets the database before each test.

Comment: Nice answer, but sequences do not always start at 1.

Answer (score 12):

Thre is special syntax in Spring for database manipulation within unit tests

```java
@Sql(scripts = "classpath:drop_all.sql", executionPhase = Sql.ExecutionPhase.AFTER_TEST_METHOD)
@Sql(scripts = {"classpath:create.sql", "classpath:init.sql"}, executionPhase = Sql.ExecutionPhase.BEFORE_TEST_METHOD)
public class UnitTest {}
```

In this example we execute *drop_all.sql* script (where we dropp all required tables) *after* every test method.
In this example we execute *create.sql* script (where we create all required tables) and *init.sql* script (where we init all required tables *before* each test method.

Comment: This is the most simple and intuitive solution I have found for such a problem.

Answer (score 4):

The command: SHUTDOWN
You can execute it using

`RunScript.execute(jdbc_url, user, password, "classpath:shutdown.sql", "UTF8", false);`

I do run it every time when the Suite of tests is finished using `@AfterClass`

Answer (score 3):

If you are using spring boot see this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34617152/how-to-re-create-database-before-each-test-in-spring)

1. Setup your data source. I don't have any special close on exit.

   datasource:
     driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
     url: "jdbc:h2:mem:psptrx"
2. Spring boot @DirtiesContext annotation

   @DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.BEFORE_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
3. Use @Before to initialise on each test case.

The @DirtiesContext will cause the h2 context to be dropped between each test.

Answer (score 1):

you can write in the application.properties the following code to reset your tables which are loaded by JPA:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

Comment: Yes but this wouldn't take care of other tables like the ones used internally for auto increments.