# How to reset H2 Database to the original state after Jhipster jdl-generation?

Tags: java, jhipster, h2, jdl

I have this project that I ran in Jhipster with the generator yo jhipster:import-jdl. When it ends, everything is clean and ready to start. This is the state I would like to easily return to, in the H2 persistent disk copy, when I do tests, changes and so on, to start all over again.

I guess that using H2 non-persistent memory would create everything every time I start the project, but is there any easy way to get that result in a disk persistent type? (Please confirm)

Or, better, is there a way to tell Jhipter to change from a memory to a persistent database to a memory persistence, at will, before you yarn start the project?

If there is no way to change this at will, I googled for a solution and it looks like I should DROP ALL OBJECTS [Reset Embedded H2 database periodically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8523423/reset-embedded-h2-database-periodically)   and then I do not know what to do to get to a clean database.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you use a H2 disk database, the files related to your database is in `target/h2db/db/` folder, with `*.db` extension.

To get a clean H2 database, you simply need to launch `./mvnw clean`, so it will delete the target folder.

Comment: is there a way to tell Jhipter to change from a memory to a persistent database to a memory persistence, at will, before you yarn start the project? Thanks Pascal

Comment: The changes required to go from disk->memory are small, but there is no automated way to do it.  Here's an example for an app with `h2switch` as the base name https://github.com/ruddell/jhipster-examples/commit/e2a5db6ecc3aada0de7519519c3376d4134fe3cd

Answer (score 0):

To clean H2 database in maven:

```
./mvnw clean
```

And In gradle:

```
./gradlew clean
```